# Wifi internet speed issue Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, internet, download-speed

I am using ubuntu 20.04 with windows on dual boot, my router is of 2.4GHz and its set to support all protocols ( b/g/n) but whenever i do speedtest on my mobile phone or when i visit windows10 they both shows speed like 20-40 Mbps and speedtesting on ubuntu yields result of just **1-2 Mbps**, i am really fed up of whats wrong. I checked on wifi properties on windows10, its shows 802.11n as protocol.

Please need immediate help on this ....

Output from **lshw -C network**

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 10
       serial: 8c:16:45:e8:01:3f
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.9.13-xanmod2 firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:16 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b2204000-b2204fff memory:b2200000-b2203fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 31
       serial: 30:d1:6b:f9:e2:b5
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=5.9.13-xanmod2 firmware=WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1 ip=192.168.101.3 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:136 memory:b2000000-b21fffff
```

And output from **iwconfig**

```
wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"XenialXerus"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.442 GHz  Access Point: E0:E8:E6:4A:07:5C   
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=55/70  Signal level=-55 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:324   Missed beacon:0
```

Comment: What is your MTU? Read `man ip ip-link` and start with `ip link`. Wireless MTU should be 1492. Fix at DHCP server.

Comment: @waltinator my MTU is showing 1500

Comment: That means that your system sends 1500 byte packets which the wireless driver has to split into TWO packets, a 1492 byte and an 8 byte. You end up sending twice as many packets. Read the `man` pages I mentioned and set your wireless MTU to 1492. The wireless protocol uses the 8 bytes. Your wireless MTU is usually set by your DHCP server (router?) but can be set with `ip link`.

Comment: Yes, i checked the router, there was a setting column to mention MTU and 1450 was default there, i changed it to 1492 ... is that it ? Or do i have to change my wireless module of system's MTU ?